# How to get user's profile pic url using graph api

Tags: php, facebook

Hi i m trying to get url of user's profile pic so I use following code

```
$userinfo = $facebook->api("/me/picture?type=large");
var_dump($userinfo);
```

but instead of returning url it returns NULL. Please help me why this is happening.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is how we can get actual picture url

```
$URL='FB GRAPH API URL';
$headers = get_headers($URL, 1); // make link request and wait for redirection
    if(isset($headers['Location'])) {
      $URL = $headers['Location']; // this gets the new url
    }
    $url_arr = explode ('/',$URL);
    $ct = count($url_arr);
    $name = $url_arr[$ct-1];
    $name_div = explode('.', $name);
    $ct_dot = count($name_div);
    $img_type = $name_div[$ct_dot -1];
    $pos = strrpos($img_type, "&");
    if($pos)
    {
        $pieces = explode("&", $img_type);
        $img_type = $pieces[0];

    }

    $imagename = imgnameyouwant'.'.$img_type;
    $content = file_get_contents($URL);
    file_put_contents("fbscrapedimages/$imagename", $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the [uid], you can simply use the following code

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/[UID]/picture" />
```

You can also crop/resize the profile picture by providing height/width parameters.

```
Eg: https://graph.facebook.com/[UID]/picture?width=140&height=140
```

If you want to use standard sizes, try

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/[UID]/picture?type=large" />
```

where type is one of {square,small,large}